# Symfony2 - FOSBundle Where do FosBundle Store SessionIDs?

Tags: symfony, session-timeout, sessionid, fosuserbundle

i wonder how can i manipulate **sessionID**s in **FOS*** bundle **Symfony2**.
i need Symfony 2 to be a Central Authentication system(kinda **AAA**).
so I want to check Given **SessionID*s from other applications requesting against **FOS** and Update their timeouts.

is FOS a good framework to do this ?
where FOS Bundle store it's SessionIDs?
and Can i Manipulate them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use JFramework instead of symfony.

Comment: JFramework is a good php framework for security reason and managing roles and permissions and session handling

Comment: where can i get it? have you ever used it under a huge project?